# Validating missing parameter from procedure calls

Tags: sql-server, validation, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which in turn calls another procedure passing parameters:

```
Alter procedure pTest 
    @IDOB datetime,
    @IName nvarchar(200)
as
    Exec pStaffInsert @IDOB
```

When I open this procedure in Management Studio, I get the following warning, which is absolutely correct:

> Procedure or function 'pStaffInsert' expects parameter '@IName', which was not supplied.

It should have been

```
Alter procedure pTest 
    @IDOB datetime,
    @IName nvarchar(200)
as
    Exec pStaffInsert @IDOB, @IName
```

I similarly have close to 500+ procedures in my application. Is there a way by which I can run a validation on all the procedures calling another with missing parameters?

I tried

```
sp_refreshsqlmodule
```

but it does not help in this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: What if the same procedure is called in application code with missing parameters?

Comment: `sp_refreshsqlmodule` procedure will not add the missing parameter in your procedure calls. It just refreshes the meta data of underlying objects. I dont think any automated way is there. You have to find the dependencies of `pStaffInsert` procedure and manually add the missing parameter

Comment: Application calls to SP are already taken care. Its SP calls from other SPs where i want to detect missing params. I assume that when sql management studio is able to give the warning, it should have an inbuild mechanism to check for valid dependencies.

Comment: `SQL Server` will not throw any warning when you add or remove any parameter. You can check the objects that are dependent on `pStaffInsert` through `T-sql` or `wizard` and update the procedure calls manually

Comment: Check this article to find the dependencies https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/